# When is access_type = Online appropriate? :OAuth2 - Google API

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-api, oauth-2.0

When requesting OAuth credentials, I can specify the access_type to be Offline or Online.

Opting for the Online access type forces the users to approve access to my app each time they login.   Why is that?   Hasn't the user already approved my app?

**Update #1:**

I have my approval_prompt set to 'auto'.
If I just log out of Google without deleting any cookies, it doesn't prompt me again.  But deleting the cookies brings back the grant screen.

**Update #2:**

It works fine through the OAuth Playground.  http://code.google.com/oauthplayground/

Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

**Update #3:**
Relevant code snippets

Helper method to generate OAuth URL

```
def build_auth_uri
    return @client.authorization.authorization_uri(
     :access_type => :online,
     :approval_prompt => :auto
    ).to_s 
end
```

Calling the Helper method in the View

```
<a href="<%= build_auth_uri %>">  Connect Me! </a>
```

Generated OAuth URL on the webpage

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=online&approval_prompt=auto&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/gclient/gcallback&response_type=code
```

Comment: Me too facing the exact issue. Find my request URL below: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&state=profile&redirect_uri=http://localhost/oacallback&response_type=code&client_id=123.apps.googleusercontent.com&approval_prompt=auto&access_type=online`

Comment: @jayyov The behavior is still erratic for me.  There seems to be a difference between doing this on localhost vs hosted website too.

Comment: Was there ever a solution to this? I'm seeing the same issue. I've also noticed that no matter how many times I approve the app does not appear in my Manage Apps page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is one other parameter that comes into play in these flows and I suspect you're running into it. It's the `approval_prompt` parameter.

When `access_type=online` you are also allowed to specify a value for `approval_prompt`. If it is set to `approval_prompt=force`, your user will always be prompted, even if they have already granted.

On the other hand, when `access_type=offline`, `approval_prompt` can only be set to `approval_prompt=force`, but to make up for this restriction you're also provided a `refresh_token` which you can use to refresh your access token.

Check the URL that your `access_type=online` is opening. Try setting `approval_prompt=auto`. The grant screen should only appear the first time.

Comment: Thanks Jenny.  I should have mentioned that I set the approval_prompt  to auto.  I still get the grant screen.   Does it depend on cookies?  I clear my cookies to retest login.  I assumed the OAuth servers store the user's approval.  If I just logout of Google without clearing all cookies, it doesn't show the grant screen.

Comment: It might. If you're clearing all of your cookies, you will be logged out of Google and you will be forced to log in again to authenticate. Do you have an example of your misbehaving code handy? I'd love to take a look :)

Comment: Thx Jenny! I added some relevant code snippets to the Question.   Do you need more?   In regards to the cookies, if the cookies are deleted, will the user be required to grant access again?  I can understand if they need to authenticate again.

Comment: @mimming access_type=offline is the best choice because the refresh token that is returned can be used ad infinitum to issue new access_tokens without having to use auth_endpoint/code routine again & again.

Comment: @mimming Is this information still current? I'm setting `access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force` and I'm still not getting an offline-access permission prompt.